# Exclude folders by name coming from config file entry

Tags: c#

I have a config file entry which lists down the folders names which can be added as needed

```
<add key="Exclude" value="Build,Runtest" />
```

in cs file i want a code to get the folders names and exclude all of them

currently the  following code is in  for single entry in config i.e

```
<add key="Exclude" value="Build" />

string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(targetdirectory, "*." + extension,    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !file.Contains(Exclude)).ToArray();
```

this above code works for single config entry

Can you help me to have a code so that it takes multiple foldernames from config file

i.e read from

```
<add key="Exclude" value="Build,Runtest" />
```

and use it in place of the existign code which is below

```
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(targetdirectory, "*." + extension,  SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !file.Contains(Exclude)).ToArray();
```